# SonarLint 3.2.0 is not showing any Analysis report for C++ code

Tags: c++, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

I have installed SonarLint 3.2.0 plugin in Eclipse(Version: Neon.3 (4.6.3)).I have Java version 8.
I have Eclipse CDT(C++).I have written a sample C++ program.From SonarLint I have bound my sample C++ project to a SonarQube project in a remote server.
Now I have done the analysis in SonarLint but in the "SonarLint Report" nothing is geting displayed(0 items).
I saw in the SonarLint console the below details.From the details I am guessing that may be the sonarlint is not able to recognize my C++ project.

```html
Trigger: MANUAL
SonarLint analysis of file /hello2/src/hello2.cpp...
Wrote build info to: C:\Users\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\hello2\org.sonarlint.eclipse.core\sonarlint2463420270089611160\build-wrapper-dump.json
Connected mode (using configuration of 'TEST1' in server 'xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx')
Starting analysis with configuration:
[
  moduleKey: TEST1
  baseDir: C:\Users\workspace\hello2
  workDir: C:\Users\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\hello2\org.sonarlint.eclipse.core
  extraProperties: {sonar.cfamily.useCache=false, sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=C:\Users\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\hello2\org.sonarlint.eclipse.core\sonarlint2463420270089611160}
  inputFiles: [
    C:\Users\workspace\hello2\src\hello2.cpp
  ]
]

Available languages:
  * JavaScript => "js"
  * Java => "java"
Start analysis
Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to js: file:**/*.js,file:**/*.jsx,file:**/*.vue
Declared extensions of language Java were converted to java: file:**/*.java,file:**/*.jav
Quality profiles:
  * java: java-sonar-way-32683 (251 rules)
  * js: js-sonar-way-79496 (86 rules)
Index files
Language of file 'C:\Users\workspace\hello2\src\hello2.cpp' is set to 'cpp'
Setting filesystem encoding: UTF-8
1 files indexed
'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
Execute Sensor: SonarJavaXmlFileSensor
Found 0 issue(s)
Done in 32 ms
```

Is there any configuration issue with my Eclipse /SonarLint or the project from SonarQube Server??

When I created a sample java project in my Eclipse and just have done the analysis without binding the SonarQube remote server
I got the below issues reported in SonarLint Report.

```html
Resource    Date    Description
Hello_java.java    null    Complete the task associated to this TODO comment.
Hello_java.java    null    Rename this class name to match the regular expression '^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.
Hello_java.java    null    Rename this package name to match the regular expression '^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$'.
Hello_java.java    null    Replace this use of System.out or System.err by a logger.
```

But for C++ program SonarLint is not working properly.am I missing any setting/configuration in SonarLint/Sonarqube project?

Comment: C++ is a paid plugin, consider contacting the customer support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Do you know how can I contact their customer support.I did not find any mail-id in their site?Only google group is mentioned there.

Comment: Your source for C-Family license key can also put you in touch with Support

Comment: Actually I do not have any license now.I would definitely like to get in touch with SonarLint support team for license.

Comment: So that means without getting paid plugin I can not analyze my C++ project with SonarLint plugin..I am searching for the support team mail